# How to link a Matlab gui to a .m file?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a .m file that contains this lines

```
%reading 2 images

image1=imread('pic1.tif');
image2=imread('pic2.tif');

% two varialbes

number_of_points = 100;
simpling = 30;
```

I want a simple gui with matlab that allow the user to :

1. select the 2 images by opening a pop-up window to explore the files on the pc.
2. choose a value  for the two variables "number_of_points" and "simpling" using radio buttons 100,150 or 200 for the first and 0 or 30 for the second.

I created a gui with matlab but I can't find a way to add those functions.

this is what it looks like :

http://s9.postimg.org/k6ed9pni7/stack.png

How can I make the gui execute my .m file with those parameters  ?

I'm a newbie so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to turn your m-file into a function that takes the four parameters as input. Than you can call your function from your *Lancer* button callback.

The alternative is to assign the values of your edit boxes & radio buttons to a variable in the base workspace and run your m-file as a script from the button's callback. If you prefer this method, you can assign variables from the GUI's functions in the base workspace (where your script will run) via `evalin('base','expression')`

Here,`'expression'` would be something like `sprintf('myPic1 = %s; myPic2 = %s; number_of_points = %d; simpling = %d;', handles.myEdit1.String, handles.myEdit2.String, handles.myRadios1.Value, handles.myRadios2.Value);`